# Fedora accessing SMB Share - Every file has x flag set

Tags: fedora, permissions, mount, samba, zfs

i have a fileserver with samba that shares 2 zfs datasets.

```
uname -a
Linux pve 4.13.16-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.13.16-45 (Wed, 28 Mar 2018 15:47:11 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
map to guest = bad user
security = user
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 2755
force create mode = 0644
force directory mode = 2755
load printers = no
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
disable spoolss = yes
show add printer wizard = no

[media]
writeable = yes
read only = no
path = /mnt/pool/media
browseable = no
guest ok = no
comment = media share
map archive = no
map system = no
map hidden = no

[stuff]
writeable = yes
read only = no
path = /mnt/pool/stuff
browseable = no
guest ok = no
comment = media share
map archive = no
map system = no
map hidden = no
```

When i access the share from any client on my network, the permissions are set to the following:

```
ls -la /stuff/file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 287 May 16 14:28
```

The clients have mixed Versions of mount.cifs, some are on 6.7 (alpine), some are on 6.2 (centos)

For some reason, a Laptop with Fedora 28 sees the permissions like this:

```
uname -a
Linux fedora-laptop 4.16.8-300.fc28.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 9 20:23:40 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.8
ls -la /stuff/file.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 287 May 16 14:28
```

Even though the command that i use for mounting the share is the same on all clients:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=user //fileserver/stuff /mnt
```

Changing the permissions with chmod -x results in no change on the Fedora Client. Changing the permissions with chmod +x lets the other clients see the execution bit, but still no change on the Fedora client.

Does someone know why the Fedora client displays the execution bit there, even tough there is none on the other clients and the fileserver?

Comment: Please include version numbers for both server and client (client kernel version).

Comment: also `mount.cifs -V`

Comment: I added the requested information. Fedora client is kernel 4.16.8-300 and cifs version 6.8, the other clients all differ from each other.

Comment: SMB/CIFS shares always have the execute bit set, because FAT and NTFS (and maybe CIFS itself) don't know what to do with POSIX file attributes and permissions. Some samba implementations even go and add all the bits and permissions to avoid incompatibilities (my music library has `777` octal set on everything from an old SMB NAS I had).

Comment: On every other system i dont have a execution bit set. Why only on fedora? And can i turn it off somehow? Some programs dont run under linux when the config file has the execution bit set.

Comment: What OS is running on the other systems?

Comment: Debian, Alpine Linux, Centos. Various operating systems, every distro shows the file without the execution bit.